# Sqlalchemy Error: MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

A Python 3.6 script access the MySQL database using SQLAlchemy when it first starts. The script then continue running for several hours without accessing the MySQL database. However when it finally decides to access MySQL, we get an error

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available. [SQL: 'SELECT ........ ]

The engine was created using

```
create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://..., pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=290)
```

The `pool_recycle` value has already been reduced to 290 seconds, much shorter than the recommended 3600 in other SO posts.

Enabling `pool_pre_ping` also did not help with reconnecting to MySQL to avoid the mentioned error.

**MySQL Variables**

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';` gave `wait_timeout` with value `28800`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'interactive_%';` gave `interactive_timeout` with value `28800`

**Software Versions**

- Python 3.5
- SQLAlchemy 1.2.2
- Ubuntu 16.04

How should we troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the mysql server to test the reconnection.
My sqlalchemy engine config in general is:

```
pool_recycle=3600,   
pool_size=5,   
max_overflow=10,   
pool_timeout=30,  
pool_pre_ping=True
```